# SQL Server - resetting a running total

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to derive a paging logic.

I have fields like:

```
RecordNo  Lines 

1          20
2          130
3          50
4          60
5          350
6          100
```

Say my pagesize is 170 lines.

The result I want to get is:

```
RecordNo Lines CumSum PageNo

1         20   20      1
2         130  150     1
3         50   50      2   (as cumulative sum 200 exceeds 170, reset to 0)
4         60   110     2
5         350  350     3   ((as cumulative sum 460 exceeds 170, reset to 0)
6         100  100     4   ((as cumulative sum 460 exceeds 170, reset to 0)
```

I can do it using cursor, but is there a way to achieve it by SQL(s) only?

Here is the ddl and sample data as posted by the OP:

```
CREATE TABLE PAGING (RECORDNO INT, LINES INT ); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(1,20); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(2,130); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(3,50); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(4,60); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(5,350); 
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(6,100);
```

Update:

Zohar, Thanks for looking into this. The query worked perfectly with the data I gave but when I extended with more data, it does not give correct result as pagebase does not move with sum exceeding 170.

Here is the data I tried the SQL with:

```
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (1, 20);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (2, 130);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (3, 50);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (4, 60);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (5, 350);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (6, 100);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (7, 20);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (8, 10);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (9, 20);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (10, 30);   
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (11, 5);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (12, 5);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (13, 5);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (14, 10);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (15, 205);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (16, 156);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (17, 5);    
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (18, 2);   
INSERT [dbo].[PAGING] ([RECORDNO], [LINES]) VALUES (19, 7);
```

Comment: What version of sql server are you using? Can you post ddl and sample data?

Comment: i am using SQL Server 2014. Sample data is in first part. It is a two column table RecordNo and Lines and the result I want to achieve is in the 2nd part

Comment: By sample data I was meaning something I can use to create a query on my end. Sure I could take the time to put it together but we are all volunteers around here and it would be a lot simpler if you did the leg work. :) Since you are using 2014 you can utilize the LAG function to create a running total and then increment a page counter when the total exceeds 170.

Comment: sorry, new to this forum,not sure about all the rules. Here is the ddl and insert  (not even sure how to put new line, as enter posts the topic)                                                                                                          CREATE TABLE PAGING
(RECORDNO INT,
LINES INT
);

INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(1,20);
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(2,130);
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(3,50);
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(4,60);
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(5,350);
INSERT INTO PAGING VALUES(6,100);
the records will be processed ORDER BY RECORDNO

Comment: I have thought about LAG AND LEAD but I am struggling to see how to reset the running total

Comment: @ManishVarma : did u get a solution to this ? with the fix for moving the pagebase

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**
Here is the complete solution [and it's fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23ba7/24):

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT RECORDNO, 
           LINES, 
           SUM(LINES) OVER (ORDER BY RECORDNO) CumSum,
           SUM(LINES) OVER (ORDER BY RECORDNO) / 170 AS PageNumberBase
    FROM PAGING
)

SELECT RECORDNO, 
       LINES, 
       SUM(LINES) OVER (PARTITION BY PageNumberBase ORDER BY RECORDNO) As CumSum,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PageNumberBase) As PageNumber
FROM cte
ORDER BY RECORDNO
```

**First version:**

Using [dense_rank](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173825.aspx) window function and a [cte](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175972.aspx) I was able to produce something very close, just the cumSum is not perfect.
Unfortunatly I don't have the time to play with it more so I'll leave it here with a link to sqlFiddle and hope the OP or someone else will be able to complete the solution:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT RECORDNO, 
           LINES, 
           SUM(LINES) OVER (ORDER BY RECORDNO) CumSum,
           SUM(LINES) OVER (ORDER BY RECORDNO) / 170 AS PageNumber
    FROM PAGING
)

SELECT RECORDNO, 
       LINES, 
       PageNumber,
       CumSum - (170 * PageNumber) As CumSum,
       DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY PageNumber)
FROM cte
```

[Here is the link to the fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/23ba7/10)