# sql reset updating rows when a value changes

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table as below:

```
  id    code   value  total
==========================
1     A/01    5       
2     A/01    8       
3     A/01    6       
1     A/02    8       
2     A/02    3       
3     A/02    7       
1     A/03    6       
2     A/03    9       
3     A/03    2
```

I want to update the total with value of same row + previous row's. I declared a variable as below and update the table:

```
DECLARE @sum int
SET @sum = 0
UPDATE @table set total = @sum, @sum = @sum + value
```

It works perfect if I select for the first code:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE code='A/01'

id    code   value  total
==========================
1     A/01    5       5
2     A/01    8       13
3     A/01    6       19
```

But if I select the whole table, then it does this:

```
  id    code   value  total
==========================
1     A/01    5       5
2     A/01    8       13
3     A/01    6       19
1     A/02    8       27
2     A/02    3       30
3     A/02    7       37
1     A/03    6       43
2     A/03    9       52
3     A/03    2       54
```

How can I update the table as I explained so it resets adding values when value in "code" column changes?? Please help, I need the following result, Thanks!

```
  id    code   value  total
==========================
1     A/01    5       5
2     A/01    8       13
3     A/01    6       19
1     A/02    8       8
2     A/02    3       11
3     A/02    7       18
1     A/03    6       6
2     A/03    9       15
3     A/03    2       17
```

Comment: Why both MySQL and MS SQL Server tags? Which dbms are you using? (Don't tag products not involved...)

Comment: sorry @jarlh It's sql server. I just removed mysql tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Update-Clause affects the whole set. So you can't define that it should reset the `@sum` after changing the code.

Try using the Window Function Sum(value) Partition by code and Order By ID

For example

```
SELECT id, value
       Sum(value) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id
                            ROWS BETWEEN UNBOUNDED PRECEDING AND CURRENT ROW) AS total     
FROM [table]
```

This set you can use to UPDATE your table.

Comment: Thank you so much @CPMunich for your quick and simple solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `windowed SUM` to calculate total:

```
WITH cte AS
(
  SELECT a.id ,   a.code , a.[value] , 
  total = SUM(a.[value]) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id)
  FROM #mytable a
)
UPDATE m
SET total = c.total
FROM #mytable m
JOIN cte c
  ON m.id = c.id 
 AND m.code = c.code;

SELECT *
FROM #mytable
ORDER BY code, id;
```

<kbd>**[`LiveDemo`](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/393569)**</kbd>

You cannot use directly windowed function in `UPDATE` like:

```
UPDATE #mytable
SET total = SUM([value]) OVER (PARTITION BY code ORDER BY id)
```

so you need to use `subquery/cte` to calculate sum first.

**EDIT:**

Your first attempt:

```
DECLARE @sum int = 0;
UPDATE @table set total = @sum, @sum = @sum + value;
```

Can be dangerous and return unpredictable results. (Forget a moment about multiple code and assume there is only `'A/01'` in table. You've assumed that sum will work row by row with increasing `id`.

But there is a catch what if parallelism is involved?

If you need this kind of operation read more about **[`quirky update`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33069463/running-total-until-specific-condition-is-true/33071417#33071417)**

Comment: Thank you @lad2025, your solution was helpful too!