# SQL Server cumulative sum with restricted range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Given a table of people and the score associated to their evaluation, I need to get their cumulative score (by person) for each evaluation.

| Person | EvaluationDate | Score |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Jane | 2012 | -12 |
| Hubert | 2014 | -5 |
| Jane | 2020 | -5 |
| Jane | 2015 | +16 |
| Hubert | 2011 | -100 |

Their scores start from 100 and cannot go below 0 or beyond 100. If at a certain time the score goes beyond 100 (or below 0), the next cumulative score is calculated from 100 (or 0).

Expected output :

| Person | EvaluationDate | Score | CumulativeScore |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Hubert | 2011 | -100 | 0 |
| Hubert | 2014 | -5 | 0 |
| Jane | 2012 | -12 | 88 |
| Jane | 2015 | +16 | 100 |
| Jane | 2020 | -5 | 95 |

There are [posts describing how to do a cumulative sum](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13331102/5546046) but they do not explain how to restrict it to a range through each operation.

Comment: Exactly, I updated the question.

Comment: It looks like you are searching for [Capping a running total](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52936314/5070879). The possible approaches for SQL Server: recursive CTE or cursor/while loop(not set-based solutions) or [quirky update(Do not use on production)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33071417/5070879)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As @LukaszSzozda advised in his comment you can use a recursive CTE.

```
with t as (
   select Person, EvaluationDate, Casescore,
       row_number() over(partition by Person order by EvaluationDate) rn
   from tbl 
), rq as(
   select *,
       case when 100 + Casescore < 0   then 0
            when 100 + Casescore > 100 then 100
            else 100 + Casescore end CumulativeScore
   from t
   where rn = 1
   
   union all 
   
   select t.Person, t.EvaluationDate, t.Casescore, t.rn,
       case when rq.CumulativeScore + t.Casescore < 0   then 0
            when rq.CumulativeScore + t.Casescore > 100 then 100
            else rq.CumulativeScore + t.Casescore end 
   from rq
   join t on t.rn = rq.rn + 1 and t.Person = rq.Person
)
select Person, EvaluationDate, Casescore, CumulativeScore
from rq
order by Person, EvaluationDate;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=02ca9c8e988f743a6f75df2e5120bbe3)

Comment: Thanks ! When handling many evaluations a recursion error is thrown, appending `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query solves the issue